# how to implement grouping by more than 2 levels in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-2013, jslink

I have an scenario to work on groupby 4 levels functionality in an list, whereas by default SharePoint has 2 levels of grouping. I have tried using client side rendering(JSlink) to achieve this, but no luck. Any one have idea to implement this functionality

[Image of group by 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvZd0.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would be glad to learn a way of doing that via CSR but so far it seems that it would take a custom data source and an XSLT data view web part.

You can probably make your life a bit easier by using XSL to render the data into JSON and then using a CSR-like approach (jslink + proper registration in MDS) to build the real DOM fragment out of the JSON island.